# Select within select at 'DataTable' with grouping

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, datatable

I'm trying to do a select within select group statement to group data, but I'm not sure how to do it in a `DataTable`.

My database looks like:

```
Breed, Name, DOB
Dog, Bob, 1/1/2012
Cat, Ben, 4/7/2012
Cat, Max, 24,1,1978
Dog, Rex, 15,9, 2000
Horse, Sue, 13/3/1999
Horse, Robby, 24,1,1990
Dog, Brodie, 24,1,1988
```

The output I am after on an ASPX master page is:

```
Dog
Bob, 1/1/2012
Rex, 15,9, 2000
Brodie, 24,1,1988

Cat
Cat, Ben, 4/7/2012
Cat, Max, 24,1,1978

Horse
Sue, 13/3/1999
Robby, 24,1,1990
```

What I have so far ungrouped is:

```xml
<asp:Repeater ID="Pets" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="PetsData">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <h3><%# Eval("Breed") %></h3>
    <p><%# Eval("Name") %> (<%# Eval("DOB") %>)</p>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and

```cs
private DataTable bindData3()
{
    string sql = @"SELECT * FROM Pets";

    DataTable dr = SqlHelper.ExecuteQuery(sql);

    Pets.DataSource = dr;
    Pets.DataBind();
    return dr;
}

protected void PetsData(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Can anyone help with the above to group the data?

---

**EDIT:** I think I am after a nested repeater so the title/breed displays once and all it's sub items are listed after that. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this using [DataTable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/way3dy9w.aspx)

It's similar to `ORDER BY` clause in SQL. You can sort your data by Breed, so that the same breed will be together.

Then, when you loop through the whole table row by row, you can check if the breed you're reading is different from the previous one. If it is different, print out the breed first then print out your data.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select p.Breed, c.Name, c.DOB
from
(
    select distinct Breed
    from Pets
) p inner join Pets c on (c.Breed = p.Breed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Pets] Group by Breed, Name, DOB